# Getting physical path of a virtual path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, server.mappath

I have a folder to hold images C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Images\eZone\Albums\Album1.
My mvc app is in another folder C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ezone. In IIS 7, I create a virtual directory **images**, which maps to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\images, under ezone site. When I run my ezone app to load images from album1

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("/images/ezone/albums/album1"));
```

it returns "C:\inetput\wwwroot\ezone\images\ezone\albums\album1" which is not correct. What am I missing?

Comment: It seems odd that its stripping out the 'ezone' from the MapPath string.  I would thing the return value would be "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ezone\images\ezone\albums\album1".  Notice the 2nd ezone

Comment: Also,  is there a reason you have the images outside of the web app folder?

Comment: Mark, actually, our administrators recommended us to leave the images folder on a separate drive for security reason. I was trying to see if I can even get it to work on a same drive.

Comment: What if you don't use Server.MapPath and just do DirectoryInfo(fullPath).  Does that work?

Comment: It assumes the folder is at the root C:\ so my next line of code trying to retrieve files from the folder throws the exception "could not find a part of the path 'C:\Images\ezone\albums\album1'."

Comment: I mean just use the full "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Images\eZone\Albums\Album1".  I don't think Server.MapPath is going to help you with this.  I think your best bet might be to have an appsetting with the fully qualified path that could contain could have different setting for dev and prod

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get virtual directory physical path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986525/how-to-get-virtual-directory-physical-path)

Answer (score 2):

Put a tilde in front of your path:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/images/ezone/albums/album1"));
```

For more information, have a look at [ASP.NET MapPath resolves Virtual, Physical Paths](http://www.dotnetperls.com/mappath)

Comment: Jens, I still get the same result.