# Directory.GetFiles Path Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have always used `Confid.VirtualDir` for my paths. For example:

```
Config.VirtualDir + "upload/gallery/image.jpg"
```

This gives me the path of **/upload/gallery/image.jpg**. which works totally fine in every page for example:

```
<img style="height: 100px; " src="<%=Config.VirtualDir + "upload/gallery/image.jpg" %>" />
```

**works perfectly fine.**

**BUT** now I have problem with **Directory.GetFiles**.

It works on:

```
protected string[] images;
images = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\website\mysite.com\upload\gallery", "*.jpg");
```

But not with:

```
protected string[] images;
string path = Config.VirtualDir + "upload/gallery";
images = Directory.GetFiles(path,"*.jpg");
```

**I don't see any errors in console.**

I also tried `"upload\gallery"` but i get error "Unrecognize escape sequence".

Using `@"C:\website\mysite.com\upload\gallery"`, will expose directory structure of my server, which I'd rather to avoid.

> **UPDATE**:  Based on **Alex K.** advice. I tried:

```
protected string[] images;
protected string realImage;
    string path = Server.MapPath(@"~\upload\Gallery");
    images = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg");
    realImage = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"~\upload\Gallery"), Config.VirtualDir + "upload/Gallery");
```

Now I'm Confused how to use path to **GetFiles** and realImage path to get my images.

> **UPDATE2**:  Got it to work. Thanks **Alex K**. I Answer below

Comment: `Server.MapPath()` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986525/how-to-get-virtual-directory-physical-path) is what you need, then take the returned file name and prefix it with the virtual directory which is what you need to send back to the client.  (`Path.Combine()` is the best want to append a file to a path)

Comment: Thanks, I tried MapPath and PathCombine. But now how can I get the files from realImage path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Description in comments:

Code File:

```
       public List<string> images = new List<string>();
        protected string realPath;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath(@"~\upload\Gallery"); 
            // this gets the actual directory path.
            realPath = Path.Combine(path, Config.VirtualDir + "upload/Gallery/");
            //this changes the path to the VirtualDir path
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            //this gets file names in the folder
            foreach(var fi in di.GetFiles())
            {
                images.Add(fi.Name);
                //adds file names to images list
            }
        }
```

HTML:

```
    <img style="height: 100px; " src="<%=realPath + images[0]%>" />
    //any images[i] is accessible
```