# How to access the virtual directory path in c#?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, .net-core

I am working on worker service and created two virtual directories inside the `IIS` server. The goal is to move files from one folder to another. The file moving part is working perfectly fine, It's just I need to provide the source and Destination directory path.

I put two folders in `wwwroot` with the name `Source` and `Destination`. I looked upon blogs and google but couldn't find any extension.

Any hint would be appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get virtual directory physical path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986525/how-to-get-virtual-directory-physical-path)

Comment: Not sire. Can i access `Server.MapPath("~/Images")` with this one?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [Microsoft.Web.Administration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=iis-dotnet) dll to get the virtual directory path. you can use the following code as a reference.

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
// get the site (e.g. default)
Site site = serverManager.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Default Web Site");
// get the application that you are interested in
Application myApp = site.Applications["/Dev1"];
// get the physical path of the virtual directory
Console.WriteLine(myApp.VirtualDirectories[0].PhysicalPath);
```

Comment: I tried but it's throwing me an exception. BTW it's a worker service, not the web application

Comment: I tried but it's throwing me an exception. `system unauthorizedaccessexception`. How can I give permission to the application

Comment: You need to run visual studio as an administrator and ensure that IIS_IUSRS has read and write permissions to the wwwroot folder.

Comment: As I said I am running this on IIS, not from Visual studio.

Comment: Your title says to get the virtual directory path in C#, if you are in iis, you only need to double-click your website and you can view the virtual directory. view its properties, you will know its path.